# Separate text to the columns

Tags: vb.net

I have this crazy text in a text file which I want to split into columns for a datagrid. Some advice on how can I do it?

```
Application: ws_cp_ixnsrv_mm DBID: 845 Status: APP_STATUS_STOPPED Runmode: EXITED 
Application: mng_dbserver_p DBID: 469 Status: APP_STATUS_RUNNING Runmode: PRIMARY 
Application: ird_dap DBID: 470 Status: APP_STATUS_UNKNOWN Runmode: EXITED 
Application: mng_dap DBID: 471 Status: APP_STATUS_UNKNOWN Runmode: EXITED 
Application: mng_messagesrv_p DBID: 472 Status: APP_STATUS_RUNNING Runmode: PRIMARY 
Application: mng_scs_p DBID: 473 Status: APP_STATUS_STOPPED Runmode: EXITED Error 
Application: pulse_collector_02 DBID: 827 Status: APP_STATUS_RUNNING Runmode: BACKUP 
Application: was_tomcat_1 DBID: 829 Status: APP_STATUS_RUNNING Runmode: PRIMARY 
Application: svc_nss_p DBID: 850 Status: APP_STATUS_RUNNING Runmode: PRIMARY 
Application: svc_nss_b DBID: 851 Status: APP_STATUS_STOPPED Runmode: EXITED Error
```

My idea: Columns:

```
Application, DBID, Status, Runmode

ws_cp_ixnsrv_mm, 845, APP_STATUS_STOPPED, EXITED
pulse_collector_02, 827, APP_STATUS_RUNNING, BACKUP
```

Comment: vba and vb.net are very different. Which one do you want?

Comment: In addition to the tags perhaps update your question with your attempts so we can at least guess if it’s vba or vb.net

Comment: You might try formatting the file contents too. Is the data on separate lines or all on a single line?

Comment: This would be much easier if "EXITED Error" was "EXITED_Error". All the rest are words except for the occasional exception. I see a lot of IndexOf and Substring in your future. Do you have any control over how the file is written in the first place?

Comment: Another irregularity. DBID 473 has no Runmode.

Answer (score 1):

When you have strings with a regularity to how they are expressed, you can use..

..a regular expression

Quick regex intro:

- `+` means "One or more of the thing to the left". The thing to the left can be a single thing, or a group of things
- `[..]` means a group of characters, which are defined between the brackets. Hyphen means a range, so `[a-z]` is "lowercase a to z", `[a-zA-Z]` is "lowercase a to z or uppercase A to Z", `[abc]` is "a or b or c", `[abce-t]` is "a or b or c or (e to t)"
- `(?<x>...)` means "whatever is matched by `...` is captured into a group (a variable) named `x`
- `\d` means "any digit", in other words, equal to `[0-9]`

The code:

```
Dim r as New RegEx("Application: (?<a>[a-z_]+) DBID: (<?d>\d+) Status: (?<s>[A-Z_]+) Runmode: (?<r>[A-Z]+)")
```

This means:

```
Application: (?<a>[a-z_]+) DBID: (<?d>\d+) Status: (?<s>[A-Z_]+) Runmode: (?<r>[A-Z]+)
^-----------^^-----------^^-----^^-------^^-------^^-----------^^--------^^----------^
     1             2         3       4        5         6            7         8
```

1. The literal string `Application:`  followed by
2. One or more of `a to z or underscore`, captured into `a` followed by
3. literal `DBID:` followed by
4. One or more of `any digit`, captured into `d` followed by
5. Literal string `Status:` followed by
6. One or more of `A to Z or underscore`, captured into `s` followed by
7. Literal string `Runmode:` followed by
8. One or more of `A to Z`, captured into `r`

And how it's used:

```
Dim s = "Application: ws_cp_ixnsrv_mm DBID: 845 Status: APP_STATUS_STOPPED Runmode: EXITED"
Dim m = r.Match(s)

m.Groups("a").Value 'it's the application column e.g. "ws_cp_ixnsrv_mm"
m.Groups("d").Value 'it's the dbid column e.g. "845"
m.Groups("s").Value 'it's the status column e.g. "APP_STATUS_STOPPED"
m.Groups("r").Value 'it's the runmode column e.g. "EXITED"
```

You'd run the `Match` for every line (read the file in and process each line in turn)

If you want "EXITED Error" in r, modify the characters class from `[A-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z ]` to include the space and lowercase chars from  `Error`

---

Alernatively, if you already know how to split strings, maybe life would be easier by doing:

```
Dim s = "Application: ws_cp_ixnsrv_mm DBID: 845 Status: APP_STATUS_STOPPED Runmode: EXITED"

s = s.Replace("Application: ","").Replace(" DBID: ","|").Replace(" Status: ","|").Replace(" Runmode: ","|")

Dim ss = s.Split("|"c)
```